# using perl can't load the file

Tags: perl, db2, dbi

My problem is about using perl to load  a local file to the db2 database. 
  the file content just like :

```
john|man|eight|usa
pis|woman|seven|china
```

split by "|",i just want load it to db2 database.
  Here is code:

```
use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::DB2;

sub main {
    $dbh = getConnect($dataSource);
    if ( defined $dbh ) {
        print "success\n";
    } else {
        print "failed。\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    print "loading file……\n";

    run_sql();

    return closeConnect($dbh);
}

sub run_sql {
    my $sqlStr = "";

    $sqlStr = "
load from '$DATA_FILE' of del modified by codepage=1208 coldel| insert into $TABLE
"
        ;
    print "$sqlStr \n";
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlStr) or return $FALSE;
    my $ret = $sth->execute();
    $sth->finish();
    if ($ret) {
        print "success!";
        return $TRUE;
    } else {
        print "failed!";
        exit(1);
    }

}
main();
```

when i run this script ,it cant't work.can someboday help me !

Comment: What is the error message? Is the LOAD statement actually understood by DB2, or is it simulated by the front-end client tools? (If you were using Informix, you'd not be able to LOAD like that; it is a statement that the various front-ends simulate, reading the file, splitting the data up and coding the INSERT statement, using placeholders of course, to get the data to the database.) Your script is incomplete; you don't show the `$dataSource`, but it probably doesn't matter. You should ensure you have DBI printing errors. You probably don't need `use DBD::DB2;` — just `use DBI;` is enough.

Comment: the error message :load from 'd:\tpa_link.sum.txt' of del modified by copdeage=1028 coldel| insert into sdata.dbo.tpa_link_sum                                                           DBD::DB2::st execute failed:[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT] SQL0104N SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: That looks like a possible value for the expanded statement, not the error message.  That should have a five-character SQLSTATE value and some text describing the problem.  At the least, use `$dbh->{PrintError} = 1;` to enable error reporting from DBI.  Consider running with DBI_TRACE=3 or even higher (9?) and analyzing what it says.

Comment: And there's the rest of the message - thanks SO for not showing it quicker.  OK; you need to find what SQLSTATE 42601 means for DB2.  When you know that, you'll be in a better position to understand what needs to be done to fix it.  Gut feel: the SQL is not syntactically valid, but the error looks fairly specific rather than general, so it may be quite easy to fix.

Comment: Note that a Google search for 'db2 sqlstate 42601 sql0104n' shows a lot of results, including previous SO questions.  And it looks like 42601 is in fact a fairly general 'you screwed up the syntax' error.

Comment: thank you,but now i still have no idea to modify it,it still can't work.

Comment: That makes two of us.  Time to go and bash the manuals. I'd start at the [DB2 10.1 InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp) and investigate the syntax of the LOAD statement, and any restrictions on where it is used.  Failing that, I'd not bother with it.  I'd create `INSERT INTO $TABLE($Col[0],$Col[1],$Col[2],…) VALUES(?,?,?,…)` with the correct table and column names, and then read the data file, split, and execute the INSERT statement with the values just read; rinse and repeat.

Comment: using "INSERT INTO $TABLE($Col[0],$Col[1],$Col[2],…) VALUES(?,?,?,…)" this way，when file is large ,load to database cast lots of time.

Comment: OK; I don't have any answer for you.  I've helped as much as I can.  You're off into the wide world on your own from here.  Or you can wait and see if anyone else who knows Perl, DBI and preferably some DB2 can help you.  I'm not able to help any more.  How often are you going to do this?  How big are the files?  Is it really too slow?  When did you measure it?  What did you compare it with? Would you be better off using the DB2 command-line tools instead of Perl and DBI?

Comment: thanks, i run this script in etl environment，if i change to use db2 command-line，then the etl can't work. the file about 2400000 rows and 300 colums，just about 2GB one file，so then load it to database a little slow.one day i have to load 200 file to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LOAD` is not an SQL statement that can be prepared, so it can not be executed via DBI (or any other SQL-only interface (like JDBC).  `LOAD` is a utility that the DB2 CLP knows how to execute.

If you can only execute via SQL, you could consider using [`ADMIN_CMD` to call the `LOAD` utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023577.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.1.0%2F3-6-1-3-0-0-12) for you, but this has the downside in that it requires that the data file be located on the database server.

Alternatively you might consider trying to use perl's `system()` call to leverage the DB2 CLP. [This SO answer shows how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832122/how-to-run-db2-import-load-using-perl) to do it.  Note that if your data file is not on the database server, you'll need to make sure that you specify `CLIENT` in your load statement (i.e. `LOAD CLIENT from $datafile ...`)